# Ошибка Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 1

Tags: html5, django

Столкнулся с ошибкой ValueError: Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 1, которая поставила меня в ступор. Пытался её решить сам, но все, что я делал лишь усугубляло ситуацию. Вот мой код:
views.py:

```
def basket(request):
    basket_elements = []
    for good in goods:
        basket_elements.append(plants.objects.get(id = '{}'.format(good)))
    context = {'basket_elements':basket_elements}
    print(context.values)
    return render(request,'content/basket.html',{'basket_elements':basket_elements})
def add_to_basket(request, id):
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        print(request.POST)
    goods.append(id)
    return cat_of_plants(request)
```

basket.html:

```
{% for i, basket_element in basket_elements %}
      <tr>
        <td class="image">
          <img src="/{{ basket_element.image.url }}/" alt="картинка не работает" width="170" height="200">
        </td>
        <td class="text">{{ basket_element.latin_name }}</td>
        <td class="text">{{ basket_element.price }} руб</td>
        <td class="text">
          <form class="" action="{% url 'quantity' basket_element.id %}">
            <input name="quantity" class="quantity" type="text" value="1">
            <button type="submit">
              <img src="{% static 'img/reload.png' %}" alt="reload">
            </button>
          </form>
        </td>
        <td class="text">
          {% if coming %}
            {{ price }}
          {% else %}
            {{ basket_element.price }}
          {% endif %}
          </td>
        <td class="text">удалить</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Вы пытаетесь разложить ваш объект внутри basket_elements на две переменные, но, очевидно, это невозможно, потому что объект нераскладываемый (не предоставляет интерфейс итератора)

Comment: @andreymal, а можно ли итерировать элементы без js?

Comment: Можно, итерируйте на здоровье всё что вам угодно, если это что угодно предоставляет соответствующий вашим требованиям интерфейс итератора.

Comment: @andreymal, хорошо, а как это сделать?

Comment: А что именно вы хотите сделать-то?

Comment: я хочу итерировать элементы, чтобы обращаться к ним по итератору

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98501/discussion-between-desertdeveloper-and-andreymal).

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, что ошибка в этой строке.

`{% for i, basket_element in basket_elements %}`

Уберите просто переменную `i`б если она не используется.

`{% for basket_element in basket_elements %}`

Если же была идея сделать, что-то вроде `for ind, item in basket_elements`, чтобы получать индекс элемента, то воспользуйтесь свойством `counter0`.

Чтобы получить индекс элемента, используйте

`{{ forloop.counter0 }}`

[Документация](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for)